# What sort of data structure can I use to deal in such a way

Tags: c++, arrays, arraylist, data-structures

The example is simplified as a toy example but I will be dealing with 1000s of nodes.

We have 5 nodes

```
t1
t2
a0
a1

t1 connects to a0 and a3
t2 connects to a0, a1, a2 and a3
a0 connects to a1
a1 connects to a0, t2
```

my final goal is to make a program that will draw the connections between nodes as well as the nodes using a graphics library.

What sort of data structure could I use. My first thought was to use linked list but I don't think that will work with this case since that data structure only uses one connection between each node.

Comment: Sounds like a `std::map<std::string, std:vector>` is a good place to start. You could also implement this as pointer-linked nodes where each node has a `std::vector<Node*>` type thing going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is graph. Depending on the ratio of the number of connections to the number of nodes, you should pick a representation that gives you enough run-time efficiency and saves memory:

- If the ratio is low (lots of nodes with relatively few connections) then the graph is *sparse*. A good data structure for representing sparse graphs is [*adjacency list*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).
- If the ratio is high (lots of nodes, each one connecting to, say, a quarter of other nodes) then the graph is *dense*. A good representation for dense graphs is [*adjacency matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

Comment: What about if I were to implement it as a hyper graph? Can this still use the same methods?

Comment: @user3371137 Hypergraphs share the same edge, so an efficient representation for them is usually a bipartite graph with vertices representing nodes connected to vertices representing hyper-edges.